# Python remove matches from list of list based on first and or second values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have the following list and I need to remove any entry where the first or second value matches any other first or second value.  See below sample for example and correct output.

The set:

```
+       [0] (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '12']) tuple
+       [1] (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '8'])  tuple
+       [2] (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '0'])  tuple
+       [3] (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['15', '0'])  tuple
+       [4] (['1', '12'], ['12', '12'], ['12', '8'])    tuple
+       [5] (['1', '12'], ['12', '12'], ['12', '0'])    tuple
+       [6] (['1', '12'], ['12', '12'], ['15', '0'])    tuple
+       [7] (['1', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['12', '0']) tuple
+       [8] (['1', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0']) tuple
+       [9] (['1', '12'], ['12', '0'], ['15', '0']) tuple
+       [10]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['12', '8']) tuple
+       [11]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['12', '0']) tuple
+       [12]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['15', '0']) tuple
+       [13]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '8'], ['12', '0'])  tuple
+       [14]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0'])  tuple
+       [15]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '0'], ['15', '0'])  tuple
+       [16]    (['12', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['12', '0'])    tuple
+       [17]    (['12', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0'])    tuple
+       [18]    (['12', '12'], ['12', '0'], ['15', '0'])    tuple
+       [19]    (['12', '8'], ['12', '0'], ['15', '0']) tuple
```

For example:

```
+       [0] (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '12']) tuple
```

Doesn't work because '1' matches '1' in the first position of pairs one and two and '12' matches '12' in the second position of pairs 1 and 3.

```
+       [12]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['15', '0']) tuple
```

Works because no first value equals any other first value and no second value equals any other second value.

Need the resulting list(or whatever data type is most appropriate) to be:

```
+       [12]    (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['15', '0']) tuple
+       [8] (['1', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0']) tuple
```

I'm a couple hours in and stuck.

Comment: that ... is not a list?

Comment: This is from temp = list(itertools.combinations(match,V))
How is that not a list?

Comment: @user3552459 Your formatting of that "list" is non-standard.  It certainly does not look like any output from `list(itertools.combinations(a,b))` that I get.  Are you using some IDE?  It might help if you specified the values for `match` and `V`.

Comment: yes, I am using IDE, I just copied that from values window.
match = [['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['12', '0'], ['15', '0']]
V = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in l if all([len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*i)])]
[(['1', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0']), (['1', '8'], ['12', '12'], ['15', '0'])]
```

if you also want the index, use `enumerate`:

```
>>> [j for j,i in enumerate(l) if all([len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*i)])]
[8, 12]
```

For each item of the list, you zip the tuple (`zip(*i)`) and check if all the items are differents using sets (`len(set(k)==3`?).

On items 0 and 8:

```
>>> zip(*l[0])
[('1', '1', '12'), ('12', '8', '12')]
>>> [len(set(k)) for k in zip(*l[0])]
[2, 2]
>>> zip(*l[8])
[('1', '12', '15'), ('12', '8', '0')]
>>> [len(set(k)) for k in zip(*l[8])]
[3, 3]
```

Then `all` checks that all item in this list is `True`, that is `==3`.

```
>>> [len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*l[0])]
[False, False]
>>> all([len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*l[0])])
False
>>> [len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*l[8])]
[True, True]
>>> all([len(set(k))==3 for k in zip(*l[8])])
True
```

And if you don't want to hard-code `==3`, you can use `==len(k)`

Answer (score 0):

I initialized a variable to simulate the right data.
If I understand what you want, the code below might work.

```
a = [(['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '12']), (['1', '12'], ['1', '8'], ['12', '8']) , (['1', '12'], ['12', '8'], ['15', '0'])]
len1 = len(a)
len2 = len1 - 1
while(len1 != len2) : 
    len1 = len(a)
    for i in a : 
        test1 = (i[0][0] == i[1][0]) or  (i[2][0] == i[1][0]) or  (i[0][0] == i[2][0])
        test2 = (i[0][1] == i[1][1]) or  (i[2][1] == i[1][1]) or  (i[0][1] == i[2][1])
        if (test1 or test2) :
            a.remove(i)
        len2 = len(a)
print(a)
```

E